# Changed authentication flow and now receiving ERROR: Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: rest, powershell

**EDIT:**

I am trying to read a token value from a text file to build a header that can be used for a REST API call.

If I request a temporary token using a credential (option T) the subsequent REST method works but if I read the permanent token in from text file (option P) on the local file system the method that worked before with the temp token fails.

> ERROR: Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Invoke-Test.ps1 (41, 13): ERROR: At Line: 41
>   char: 13 ERROR: + $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers
>   $headers -Uri "$ap ... ERROR: +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ERROR:     +
>   CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:
>   (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>   WebException ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Code:

```
# Allow the use of self-signed SSL certificates, TLS
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $True }
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$server = "https://192.168.1.1" 
$app_rest = "$server/api/v1"

$choice = Read-Host "Enter T or P"
If($choice -eq "T") {   
    Write-Host "Try and obtain temp token"
    $Username = Read-Host "Enter Username" 
    $Password = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
    $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)
    $Password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)

            $creds = @{
            username = $Username
            password = $Password
            grant_type = "password"
            };
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$server/api/token" -Body $creds
    $token = $response.access_token
    Write-Host $token
}
ElseIf($choice = "P") {
    Write-Host "Try and use perm token"
    #$token = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\temp\SBXtoken.txt")
    $token = Get-Content "C:\temp\SBXtoken.txt" -Raw
    Write-Host $token
}
Else {Break;}

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $headers -Uri "$app_rest/status" 
$status = $response.status;
Write-Host $status
```

Comment: At a complete loss here. If I always run the first irm by taking those lines out of the If statement and always run through them then all subsequent irm work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're running as administrator
2. Change your code because powershell doesn't respond to operators the same as formal programming languages.

   ```
   ElseIf($choice -eq "P") {
       Write-Host "Try and use perm token"
       #$token = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\temp\SBXtoken.txt")
       $token = Get-Content "C:\temp\SBXtoken.txt" -Raw
       Write-Host $token
   }
   ```